# Как сообщение в Discord запомнить в переменной? (discord py)

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Суть задачи:
Пользователь пишет сообщение в Discord. Если оно начинается с "$", то в переменную R запомнить текст всего сообщения.
Как написать условие я знаю, а как запомнить в переменную само сообщения - без понятия

---

вопрос закрыт я разобрался.......

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@commands.command() #или @bot.command(); вместо bot ваша переменная
async def cmd(ctx):
    R = message.content
```

ctx: [discord.ext.commands.Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context)
message: [discord.Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message)